# Managing Service Worker cache

Tags: javascript, service-worker

The service worker code I'm currently experimenting with looks like this in part

```
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        caches.open('v1').then(function(cache) {
            return cache.addAll([
                '/react-redux/node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js',
                '/react-redux/node_modules/react-dom/dist/react-dom.js',
                '/react-redux/a.js'
            ]);
        })
    );
});
```

With of course the standard fetch event listener that returns from cache, or runs a network request if the item is not there.

But what if, from the example above, `a.js`, and only `a.js` is updated—how do I get the service worker to update that file, but ***only*** that file; and how do I ensure that the next time the user browses to my page, they *won't* pull the now-stale version of the file from the service worker?

The best I can imagine would be to add a cache buster to those file urls, for example

`'/react-redux/node_modules/react/dist/react-with-addons.js?hash=1MWRF3...'`

then update whatever module loader I'm using to request these files with that same, current hash/cache buster, and then in the SW install event iterate over the current cache keys and delete anything that's stale, and add anything that's missing.

That *would* seem to solve both problems: when a file is updated, the network request that's sent won't match anything in the now-stale Service Worker, and so the same network fallback will happen; and the selective cache insertion in the Service Worker's install event wouldn't try to add things to the cache that are already there and current.

And of course the Service Worker code would change as these hash values change (automatically from a build process) and so getting the SW to re-install when files change would happen, as well.

But I can't help but think there's a simpler way.  Is there?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your understanding of what should ideally happen, and the difficulties in making sure that cached assets are updated efficiently and reliably, is spot-on.

While you could roll your own approach, there are existing tools that will automate the process of fingerprinting each file and then generating a service worker file that manages your cached assets. I've developed one of them, [`sw-precache`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache). [`offline-plugin`](https://github.com/NekR/offline-plugin) is another alternative that covers similar ground.

Comment: Outstanding - will look at those resources.  Thanks a ton.  So ... do you know / work with Jake Archibald? :)

Comment: Yes, I do have the distinction of being Jake's coworker!

Comment: So sw-precache - how in the world does it integrate with the client side / module loading? You could be using Webpack, SystemJS, or other options - does sw-precache output the correct url's to use, with it being your responsibility to sync them with your client loader?

Comment: `sw-precache` takes a look at the filenames that exist locally once your build is complete, and will use URLs based on those to populate its cache. There shouldn't be a specific need to adjust your client loader. If you do run into issues, please let us know via https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/issues

Comment: Sure, but what if file X changes - how do you prevent the now-stale X that's already in the SW cache from loading on the next browse?  Do you remove it in SW's activate, and guarantee the page won't start until you're done?

Comment: In general, using a cache-first strategy implies that everything is going to be "stale" on the next visit, and updates are only visible on the N+1 visit. Detecting SW updates and then displaying a "Please reload..." toast message is the current UX best practice for this.

Comment: E.g. https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-precache/blob/master/demo/app/js/service-worker-registration.js#L36

Comment: Great answer. Some additional info https://jakearchibald.com/2016/caching-best-practices/#the-service-worker-the-http-cache-play-well-together-dont-make-them-fight

Comment: @jeff If next visit stale is ok / current best practice - would it also be feasible to store current file-hashes in indexeddb - and compare with current in SW install code, to determine what needs to be re-loaded?

Comment: Yes, using IndexedDB to keep track of that info is one approach. There is a WIP rewrite of `sw-precache` underway, that uses IndexedDB for fingerprints: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/sw-helpers/blob/master/packages/sw-precaching/src/lib/models/revision-details-model.js

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing the code for exactly what you said, here is the code for anyone having difficulties writing it themselves:

Firstly, we need to write the code to add a timestamp/hash to URL of the bundle file everytime the bundle changes.

Most of us use webpack for bundling the application together, and every time the webpack config file is executed the bundle supposedly changes so we will do the hash/timestamp insertion in URL here. I have a file named `index.template.html` where I store the file served to the user so to modify the URL I did this:

```
// webpack.config.js

const webpack = require('webpack');
const fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('./public/index.template.html', function (err, data) {
    if (err) return console.log('Unable to read index.template file', err);
    fs.writeFile('./public/index.template.html',
        // finding and inserting current timestamp in front of the URL for cache busting
        data.toString('utf8').replace(/bundle\.js.*"/g, "bundle\.js\?v=" + Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + "\""),
        (err) => {
            if (err) console.log("Unable to write to index.template.html", err);
        });
});

module.exports = {
    // configuration for webpack
};
```

Now here is the code for service worker which detects the change in URL and re-fetches and replaces the resource in the cache in case of a change, I've tried to explain the working in comments:

```
self.addEventListener("fetch", function (event) {
    event.respondWith(
        // intercepting response for bundle.js since bundle.js may change and we need to replace it in our cahce
        event.request.url.indexOf('public/bundle.js') != -1 ?
        checkBundle(event.request) : //if it is the bundle URL then use our custom function for handling the request
        caches.match(event.request) //if its not then do the use service-worker code:
            .then(function(response) {
                // other requests code
            })
        );
});

// our custom function which does the magic:
function checkBundle(request) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){ // respondWith method expects a Promise
        caches.open(cacheName).then(function(cache) {
             //first lets check whether its in cache already or not
             // ignoreSearch parameter will ignore the query parameter while searching in cache, i.e., our cache busting timestmap
            cache.keys(request, { ignoreSearch: true }).then(function(keys) {    
                if(keys.length == 0) {
                    // its not in cache so fetch it
                    return resolve(fetch(request).then(
                        function (response) {
                            if (!response || (response.status !== 200 && response.status !== 0)) {
                                return response;
                            }                  
                            cache.put(request, response.clone());                           
                            return response;
                        }
                    ));
                }
                //it is in cache, so now we extract timestamp from current and cached URL and compare them
                const lastVersion = /bundle.js\?v=(.*)$/.exec(keys[0].url)[1],
                    curVersion = /bundle.js\?v=(.*)$/.exec(request.url)[1];

                if(lastVersion == curVersion) // if timestamp is change that means no change in the resource
                    return resolve(cache.match(request)); //return the cached resource

                //bundle file has changed, lets delete it from cache first
                cache.delete(keys[0]);
                //now we fetch new bundle and serve it and store in cache
                var fetchRequest = request.clone();
                resolve(fetch(fetchRequest).then(
                    function (response) {
                        if (!response || (response.status !== 200 && response.status !== 0)) {
                            return response;
                        }                  
                        cache.put(request, response.clone());                           
                        return response;
                    }
                ));
              });
        });
    });
}
```

[As mentioned by Jeff Posnick in the comment of other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41616947/managing-service-worker-cache#comment70437960_41617891) generally these types of method require N+1 visits to see the updated resource but this one doesn't as the resource is re-fetched then served to the client and replaced in the cache at the same time.